# How to use the Aggrete(), Lookup() helpers in Mongo C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am new to using MongoDb. It's taken me some solid hours to be able to wrap my head around using it.

There are multiple ways to skin the cat here. I'm hoping someone could give some clarity on a method I'm leaning towards using.

There's the traditional Bson code from Atlast compass I can move over and use in my C# code, but it's ugly and cumbersome. I currently have it listed in three steps to get what I want.
I'll post it near the bottom because it's a garbled mess.

Then I have a .Aggregate collection. Mixed with a Match and Lookup. A one to many lookup. What isn't really listed anywhere is how to have multiple Matches within the Lookup.

```
    var result = await collection
    .Aggregate()
    .Match(c => c.ExposureInputs.Contains("Outdoor")) //start the match at the first collection
    .Lookup(
        _sensorDataCollection, // joined on collection
        c => c.Id,
        s => s.MainFileId,
        (Sensors c) => c.sensorData // I need to then add a match on this list of data . > || < type thing
    )
    .ToListAsync();
```

That c.sensorData is a List created in the Sensors model. I want to limit the number of results sent back as this particular Lookup brings back the entire initial match collection. Basically I want to replicate the BsonDoc below. There doesn't seem to be a way to add the AND ..which MQL uses ..

I don't want to bring the whole collection then filter on it.. Hoping to do as the Bson doc does and build on the query.

```
Here's the Bson Stuff  (which I hope to replicate in the above code).. which does work, but it's bulky. 

    var filter = new BsonDocument[]
{
    new BsonDocument("$match",
    new BsonDocument("ExposureInputs",
    new BsonDocument("$in",
    new BsonArray
                {
                    "Outdoor"
                }))),
    new BsonDocument("$lookup",
    new BsonDocument
        {
            { "from", "AcuitySensorData" },
            { "let",
    new BsonDocument("id", "$_id") },
            { "pipeline",
    new BsonArray
            {
                new BsonDocument("$match",
                new BsonDocument("$expr",
                new BsonDocument("$and",
                new BsonArray
                            {
                                new BsonDocument("$eq",
                                new BsonArray
                                    {
                                        "$mainFile_Id",
                                        "$$id"
                                    }),
                                new BsonDocument("$gt",
                                new BsonArray
                                    {
                                        "$AirTemp",
                                        11.3
                                    }),
                                new BsonDocument("$lt",
                                new BsonArray
                                    {
                                        "$AirTemp",
                                        21.1
                                    })
                            })))
            } },
            { "as", "sensor_data" }
        })
};


var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<Sensors, BsonDocument>
        .Create(filter);

var data = await collection.Aggregate(pipeline).ToListAsync();
```

Does any know how to do this? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my own problem. It doesn't solve all of it, but I'll ask another .. shorter question to try and get it resolved.

The solution was to just add another match to my Lookup. Mongo syntax will use AND.. using IAggregate() method you just add another match..

```
var result = await collection
            .Aggregate()
            .Lookup<Sensors, SensorData, CompletedSensorData>(_sensorDataCollection, a => a.Id, a => a.MainFileId, a => a.LookUpSensorData)
            .Match(a => a.ExposureInputs.Contains("Outdoor"))
            .Match(e => e.LookUpSensorData.Any(e => e.AirTemp > 18 & e.AirTemp < 21)) 
            .ToListAsync();
```